# How to Import Adafruit_GPIO.SPI

Tags: raspberry-pi3, sensors

I've been working on Raspberry-Pi3 and SHARP IR-sensor(2Y0A02 F 8Z),i've imported all the dependencies but still i get the error as :
**Import Error: No Module named Adafruit_GPIO.SPI**

I've installed Adafruit_GPIO :
pip3 install Adafruit_MCP3008

```
import time
    import Adafruit_GPIO.SPI as SPI
    import Adafruit_MCP3008
    CLK=18
    MISO=23
    MOSI=24
    CS=25
    mcp=Adafruit_MCP3008.MCP3008(clk=CLK,cs=CS,miso=MISO,mosi=MOSI)
    while True:
        v=(mcp.read_adc(0)/1023.0)*3.3
        dist = 16.2537 * v**4 - 129.893 * v**3 + 382.268 * v**2 - 512.611 * v + 301.439
        print("Distance {:.2f}".format(dist))
        time.sleep(2)
```

This is the Error generated:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "test1.py", line 2, in <module>
     import Adafruit_GPIO.SPI as SPI
     ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Adafruit_GPIO'
```